# In excel Is it possible to apply freeze panes in page layout mode?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

In my excel sheet I have freezed the first lines because I want some data to always be visible. So I went to the view tab> freeze panes. This is fine when I am in view mode on normal, however if I put the page layout view mode then freeze panes does not work. Is there a way with VBA to freeze the first few rows of a sheet while in page layout mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page layout, you cannot do this. And if you apply freeze, then you cannot see the freeze in page layout.